# REST API Call - Request Timeout

Tags: apexrest, mobilesdk, angularjs, salesforce-sdk-hybrid, hybrid-local

Hybrid Mobile App 
Cordova 8.0.0 
Angular 1.7.5 
Salesforce MobileSDK 6.2

Method - force.apexrest

Issue - Salesforce REST API Call - Request Timeout (20%).

Details - When the mobile app is hitting an SFDC custom REST API then sometimes it gets Request Timeout (incase app does not get the response from SFDC API within a time period).

Is there any configuration setting in Mobile SDK where we can set (increase) this timeout period ?

Comment: But you don't know what is causing this request time out, right?

Comment: We are sending some(50+) records as JSON Payload while hitting the API and those records are getting upserted in SFDC and then there are some triggers, process builders. So this entire transaction would be taking so long and may be the cause of Request Timeout I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I think that your best approach could be:

> 1. Fully analyzing your transaction and detecting which codes/ workflows / triggers... in general, the full apex transaction that is
>      affecting this Call.
> 2. To can track the and set the time of your Call Out to have an idea of what is happening and in combination with the developer console you
>      can detect when you are reaching this limit and based on that act
>      accordingly.

I will suggest to take a look to [**this link**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_timeouts.htm).

There is relevant information that will help you to investigated in which moment yo uare reaching this limit.

You can look the [**Apex Limit Class**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_limits.htm) to help you with several limits to in your transaction:

```
getCpuTime()
```

> Returns the CPU time (in milliseconds) accumulated on the Salesforce
>   servers in the current transaction.

```
getLimitCpuTime()
```

> Returns the time limit (in milliseconds) of CPU usage in the current
>   transaction.

So you probably need to look your code as a full transaction for that Call out. What is firing, what is the full range of that operation. After having that clear you can start detecting why the call is timing out. It could be a SOQL, it could be that you are firing to many future calls or anything else that is costing and using execution time. Use the **Limit Class** to detect your limits.

I think in this situation with many components involve in a transaction you need to examine everything in order for you to get to the bottom of the problem. Run always the developer console behind to get log information. You could also deactivate some of the components that are part of your full transaction to see if perhaps they are the one causing this problem. Workflows, Triggers, or other components can be switch off to help you detect the main reason of why you are reaching this limit. Run the Call out clean of dependencies and check if you get what you expect. Start activating other components until to see which one is affecting the call out...this is probably the best way.

Run this call out in a separated sandbox, clean one with no other code. If the call out works fine there then you know start doing what I mentioned above, deactivation and activation of others parts of that transaction.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I appreciate the way you explained this.